# Can't insert DateTime into SQL Server from Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I can't seem to insert DateTime into SQL Server using Python

Here is my code:

```
def execute_query_commit(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        print("Query executed and committed")
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")

email = input("Email: ")
credcard = int(input("Enter number:"))
now = datetime.now()

query = f''' \
    insert into testing1 (email, credcard, transactiondetails)
    values ({email},{credcard},{now})'''

conn = create_connection()
execute_query_commit(conn,query)
```

The datatype for the `transactiondetails` column in SQL Server is DateTime.

If I hardcode the values: `'2020-06-03 18:09:23'` - it works.

However, if I use `{now}`, the error occurs at `18`

```
The error '('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '18'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")' occurred
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Parametrise your query, and this error is going to disappear.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this. How can I do it?

Comment: I, personally, only started doing anything with Python about a month ago and I've not done anything with SQL Server with it (intentionally). I don't doubt, however, that the results [here](https://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+How+do+you+parametrise+a+SQL+Query+in+Python) will give you a lot of guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to pass in python datetime.now() then you'll need to format the string

```
f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
now.strftime(f)
```

However I would recommend parameterise the SQL

Comment: Hi, how should I do this? I cant seem to get it

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after formatting the string.

Comment: If you do print(now.strftime(f)) that should match the format of the hardcoded value.  Have you put quotes single around {now}?